# SQL Get top record from hex column

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server 2008, what is the best way to get the top record, by descent order from a hexadecimal column?

Let's assume I have these records:

```
epc                     ,UPC
-------------------------------
30342C30D01DADC00000031A,123456
30342C30D01DADC00000031B,123456
30342C30D01DADC00000031C,123456
30342C30D01DADC00000031D,123456
```

I've done already a search of this assignment. And this is the query I made:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
   EPC,
   CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), '0x' + epc, 1)) AS 'SERIAL' 
FROM 
   myTable
WHERE 
   upc = @upc 
ORDER BY 
   SERIAL DESC
```

This works, it returns me the EPC then the top hex, in dec value. But I just need the EPC.

I'm not sure if this is the right way. That's why I'm asking for advice.

Note: this query is executed from a C# app. And we are no allowed to create stored procedures.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: How about `order by epc desc`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT TOP 1 EPC
WHERE upc=@upc
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), '0x' + epc,1)) DESC;
```

You can put an expression in `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE

```
;WITH C AS(
    SELECT TOP 1 EPC,CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),'0x' + epc,1)) AS 'SERIAL'
    FROM myTable
    WHERE upc=@upc
    ORDER BY SERIAL DESC
)
SELECT EPC FROM C
```

Comment: You can't use an `order by` in a CTE like that. You need the `order by` on the main query.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 EPC 
FROM(
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT 
        EPC,
        CONVERT(INT,CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX),'0x' + epc,1)) AS 'SERIAL' 
    FROM myTable
    WHERE upc = @upc 
    ORDER BY 2 DESC
)A
```

Comment: Using `top 100 percent` in a view or derived table is optimized out from the query plan and never used. You need the order by clause in the main query to make sure you get the correct value back.

Comment: So are you saying that their is no surety that the correct value would be returned if I use `TOP 1` on an already sorted table(in this case a derived table) ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am saying. And here is a SQLFiddle to prove my point. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bd06c/1